# Js 2 dimensional array error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multidimensional-array

I am trying to save values from parsed xml. And I am getting this kind of error. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: `xmlValues[i++]` is undefined

Comment: i is not 0 at a beggining? ... so xmlValues[0][0]  ??

Comment: Maybe it doesn't hit it on the first iteration, could be `xmlValues[71][0]` depending on how many `zadanie` elements there are. Anyway, [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) can give you the `index` of each element so there is no need to keep incrementing your own `i` variable

Comment: What's the value of `i` just before your exception? I assume it's >= 3 but `xmlValues` has only 3 elements at indices 0, 1, 2. Access for other indices returns undefined and you try to access index 0 of `undefined`.

Comment: but i have set i to 0 at line 32 ...

Comment: @TomP If you have more than 1 `zadanie` element you increment `i` for each and will get an error in your code because you assume that you have only 1 of each of `zadanie`, `napoveda` and `riesenie`. If only one of those exists more than once in your xml then you increment `i` more than once and will access `xmlValues` at a wrong index.

Comment: no it will not after every for each i set i to 0 i tested i in for each using console.log ... it was good from 0 to 5

Comment: @TomP I overread that you set `i=0` between the calls to `find`, sorry. At what value of `i` does your code fail? Are you sure you don't want `xmlValues[0][i++]` (first and second index swapped), because this way it would make sense :). For your other elements `napoveda` and `riesenie` the indices should be switched as well I think.

Comment: i van it like  zadanie napoveda riesenie , zadanie napoveda riesenie  ......

Answer (score 0):

you currently have it looking for an incrementing value which you cant even print out( i++) you have to have it look for i explicitly THEN increment it

```
xmlValues[i][0] ....
i++
```